# How to provide inputs to installation prompts using python?

Tags: python

How to provide prompts to an installation.

```
enter import paramiko
from scp import SCPClient

def createSSHClient(server, port, user, password):
   client = paramiko.SSHClient()
   client.load_system_host_keys()
   client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   client.connect(server, port, user, password)
   return client

stdin, stdout, stderr = createSSHClient('IP', 22, 'username', 'password').exec_command('./binfile.bin')
```

I have prompts like.
Do you wish to update (y/n):
Confirm changes(y/n)

How can I automatically handle and provide the inputs in a script?

Comment: Please read about `input()`

Comment: if possible can a script be present the machine(linux) which can do this so that the script can be executed to handle this,

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: what I meant to say is if a script which can handle the installation and prompts can be created in the linux machine then the script can be executed remotely if  we cannot pass the inputs for these prompts through the SSHClient

Comment: Solved.
pass the command to the remote machine as   ' yes | ./script'
After some more research with a bit more search, I found that this question is duplicate and the answer is already there.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin, stdout, stderr = createSSHClient('IP', 22, 'username', 'password').exec_command(' yes |./binfile.bin')`

This solved the problem.